# Azure PHP Contact Form to email issues

Tags: php, azure

So I have a contact form and a PHP script coded on Dreamweaver. All has been uploaded to the Remote Server. A Web App has been created in Azure.

However, upon testing this, I get the good old "This page cannot be displayed" page that we all love!

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
 if(isasset($_POST{'formSubmit'})){
  $name=$_POST['firstName'];
  $surname=$_POST['surname'];
  $companyName=$_POST['companyName'];
  $email=$_POST['yourEmail'];
  
  $to='todd.gilbey@indomtrading.com';
  $subject='Form Submission';
  $message="Name: ".$name."\n"."Surname: ".$surname."\n". "Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$companyName;
  $headers="From: ".$email;
  
  if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
   echo("Sent Successfully");
  }
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<form action="handler_mail.php" method="post">

 <input class="formInput" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name"/><br>
 <input class="formInput" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surnames"/><br>
 <input class="formInput" type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Company/Production Name"/><br>
 <input class="formInput" type="email" name="yourEmail" placeholder="Email address"/><br>
</form>
```

According to the Azure help team, the web app person already has PHP enabled so I don't see what the problem is.

I have my coding here to see if anyone has any idea what I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: What does your folder structure in the Azure Web App look like?

Comment: [Click here to view the screenshot of my folder structure](https://imgur.com/8XVHzkp)
The PHP file is on the PHP Documentation Folder. The 'default' page sits in the root folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code:

```
if(isasset($_POST{'formSubmit'})){
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST{'formSubmit'})){
```

that might cause an error.

Comment: Well spotted. Thank you, Ill try this and let you know the outcome.

Comment: thanks, feel free to mark it as answer if it helped :)

Comment: Not so shockingly it didn't solve it. But I'm giving up now anyway. I'm tired of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure App Service, you should put all website pages into the default folder for IIS (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`).

[image]

You can change it from the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com) if needed.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing. However, I go into the **Kudu** then **CMD Console** and there's no directory there - despite specifying the folder directory as seen in the [image here](https://imgur.com/RWnd6c9)

Comment: Also, this might help too. This is the page I get then I click the **Submit** button. [Click here](https://imgur.com/a/dyOH6). As you can see in the address bar - the last item in the address directory is the PHP Document instead of the **echo** command being displayed in the browser. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting `handler_mail.php` file into `Pages` folder?

Comment: Yes I did. I moved it into the same directory as the default page (the root) but made no different. Basically - the result is the same regardless as to where I put the documents. Do I also need to define a testing server in Dreamweaver or can I just test this on the Azure remote server? Thanks

Comment: This is the folder structure on the remote server as per Dreamweaver [click here] (https://imgur.com/bitc2R2). Thanks

Comment: Open the App Service Editor via this endpoint `https://tastefullyobscene.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/` and see what files there.

Comment: Well, I can load `handler_mail.php` with this URL `http://tastefullyobscene.azurewebsites.net/handler_mail.php` and it returns 200 OK, not 404.

Comment: Does this mean that I should be able to fill in the form and sent it to my email? I tried the link & I'm now just getting a blank page....?

Comment: You may need to change `<form action="handler_mail.php" method="post">` to `<form action="/handler_mail.php" method="post">`.

Comment: Would I need to define a local testing server in addition to uploading everything to the remote? Thanks

Comment: Oh wow, shocker, still doesn't work! You know what, I give up with this thing. I've had enough of it. I'm done.